# Python exception class not defined, no attribute

Tags: python, exception

I am currently using pytesseract which defines an exception class as follows:

```
class TesseractError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, status, message):
        self.status = status
        self.message = message
        self.args = (status, message)
```

in my main.py, I tried several ways to use this exception for exception handling but I've gotten no "TesseractError" attribute error and no "TesseractError" defined error.

1.

```
>>> from pytesseract import TesseractError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'TesseractError'
```

2.

```
>>> import pytesseract
>>> try: raise pytesseract.TesseractError(True,"True")
... except TesseractError: print("error")
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'pytesseract' has no attribute 'TesseractError'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
NameError: name 'TesseractError' is not defined
```

3.

```
>>> import pytesseract
>>> try: raise TesseractError(True,"True")
... except TesseractError: print("error")
...

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'TesseractError' is not defined

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
NameError: name 'TesseractError' is not defined
```

However, when I try the following in terminal, it just works.

```
>>> class ERR(Exception): pass
>>> try: raise ERR()
... except ERR: print("error found")
error found
```

so it seems it's the importing step is wrong but I don't know what caused it.

Comment: That exception isn't exposed at the top level of the package, only `image_to_string` is. If you want it, you'll have to `from pytesseract.pytesseract import TesseractError`.

Comment: It worked! How does top-level exposure work here?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. What is available directly from the package is defined by [`__init__.py`](https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract/blob/master/src/__init__.py), everything else must be accessed explicitly by module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the `__init__` file:

[https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract/blob/master/src/**init**.py](https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract/blob/master/src/__init__.py)

Notice that it does not import the `TesseractError` to be visible from the package itself. You could either change the **init** file or import from the package>module>

```
from pytesseract.pytesseract import TesseractError
```

Comment: Note that your `import *` will be affected by [`__all__`](https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract/blob/master/src/pytesseract.py#L23).

Comment: ah, just saw that - they only put image_to_string there too :/

Comment: so my understanding is when I called "import pytesseract", "____init____" is called and only "from pytesseract import image_to_string" is executed. And when I try "from pytesseract.pytesseract import TesseractError", I am importing TesseractError class from pytesseract.py of pytesseract folder/library. Is that right?

Comment: That's correct. It all comes down to the distinction between packages and modules: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/111871/module-vs-package

Comment: Thanks guys! it helped!